# Changing Background Color of Selection Rows using MapBasic?

Tags: mapbasic

In MapInfo Pro 12.5, in the Browser window, selected rows (selected either by clicking rows with the mouse or via a query) are highlighted dark blue but running the same queries in a MapBasic program selection rows in the browser window are highlighted light grey.

In MapBasic is there a system setting to change the selected row highlight colour in the browser window (either to a deeper grey or dark blue). I have checked the MapBasic Reference manual, MapInfo System settings, googled etc. but have not been able to find anything.

Where might I be able find this in the Reference or User manuals?

Answer (score 2):

There should be no difference to how you select the records - they should appear the same.

One thing that does affect the appearance is whether the browser window is the active window or not. If the browser window is active, the selected records are shown with a dark blue colour. If the browser window isn't active, the selected records are shown with a light grey colour.

Try making your browse the active window in your MapBasic program:

```
Set Window nBID Front
```

where nBID is an Integer variable referring to your browser window

Comment: Beat me to it this time Peter! :-)

Comment: You can't win them all, Tom :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to change the row highlight colour for a selected row and I suspect that the selected rows are highlighted grey when your browser window is not the window in focus. Try it out in MapInfo, open a browser window and select a row, it should be highlighted blue. Now open another window and note that the selected row in the now unfocused browser window will have turned light grey.

Have you tried setting the browser window as the front window?

e.g.

`Set Window winID Front`